# Minecraft Mod textoutput with symbols

Tags: minecraft

```
$${
log("ü");
}$$
```

I dont really know much about programming and coding. I only want to change a script somebody gave me.
The problem is that letters like "Ü" wont show up correctly. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your *build.gradle* file:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```